# Create a list from while loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have while loop. And I want to create a list from while loop. I mean I need to append each result of loop to the list. I am sharing my code belog.

```
length = len(filtered)
i = 0
  
# Iterating using while loop
while i < length-1:
    a = filtered[i+1][0], (float(filtered[i+1][1])-float(filtered[i][1]))/(float(filtered[i][1]))
    
    listt=list(a)
    
    i += 1
    
    print(listt)
```

Comment: define a list outside of whileloop(`x=[]`) and use `x.append(your_val)`?

Comment: `listt=list(a)` is just going to create a brand new list from `a` every time, and throw out the old `listt`.

Comment: It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initiate a list: `variableName=[]` (before the while loop)
2. In the while loop add values, either with `variableName.append(value)` or `variableName+=[value]`

Answer (score 1):

Declared an `lst[]` outside of while loop. Then append `a` to list.

```
length = len(filtered)
i = 0

# Iterating using while loop
lst = []
while i < length-1:
    a = (filtered[i+1][0], (float(filtered[i+1][1]) -float(filtered[i][1]))/(float(filtered[i][1])))
    lst.append(a)
    i += 1
print(lst)
```